# Which mode is IE6 if doctype is html as HTML5?

Tags: html, browser, internet-explorer-6, doctype, quirks-mode

If web page has doctype as HTML5.

```
<!doctype html>
```

Which render mode is it for IE6?

The **document.compatMode** tells **CSS1Compat**. It looks Standard mode, not quirks mode. But, is it true? IE6 is released before HTML5 term is coined. How can IE6 recognize HTML5 doctype?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The HTML5 doctype was specifically chosen because it was the shortest doctype string possible that triggered standards mode in all browsers (starting with IE6). This was a deliberate decision based on what what would work in browsers that were already in use.

In other words, if you specify `<!doctype html>`, IE6 should go into standards mode, not quirks mode.

The reason it works is because IE6 (and others) are actually quite lenient on the doctype; they're making the assumption that if there's a doctype there, the developer probably intended to be in standards mode. If they don't recognise it, they're assuming that either the developer made a typo or there's been a new doctype invented that wasn't around when the browser was released; either way, the browser attempts to make the best of it and work in standards mode. The HTML5 team discovered that `html` was the shortest doctype string possible which triggered this behaviour, hence its use as the HTML5 doctype.

What the HTML5 doctype *doesn't* do of course is trigger old browsers like IE6 to actually support any of the new HTML5 features. This is obvious really. Products like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and [HTML5Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) can help with that, but only up to a point.