# Why Firefox highlights HTML transitional doctype in red?

Tags: html, firefox, doctype

It looks like Firefox is treating it like an error. What does this mean?

[image]

Firefox treats it normally if I change it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

BTW I'm on Firefox 12.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you hover over that red line, Firefox gives you the answer.

> Almost standards mode doctype. Expected `“<!DOCTYPE html>”`

The markup of the View Source also hints its an error doctype

```
<span class="error doctype" title="Almost standards mode doctype. Expected “<!DOCTYPE html>”.">
    &lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"&gt;
</span>
```

The point is, Firefox wants `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the [standard mode doc-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla%27s_Quirks_Mode).

Update:

Excerpt from the above given link.

> The DOCTYPE shown in the example, `<!DOCTYPE html>`, is the simplest
>   possible, and the one recommended by HTML5. Earlier versions of the
>   HTML standard recommended other variants, but all existing browsers
>   today will use full standards mode for this DOCTYPE, **even the dated
>   Internet Explorer 6**. There are no valid reasons to use a more
>   complicated DOCTYPE. If you do use another DOCTYPE, you may risk
>   choosing one, which triggers almost standards mode or quirks mode.

Comment: That's HTML5 right? Is it perfectly OK to start using HTML5 right now without compromising "old school" users?

Comment: please check the link I have sent you.

Comment: @IMB -- yes, it's fine to use HTML5 doctype: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935065/which-mode-is-ie6-if-doctype-is-html-as-html5/5935116#5935116

Comment: @Spudley and naveen Thanks, I am now quite hooked with HTML5 just at this moment (as I've been hesitant for months). Now doing some search, I've found about HTML5 Boilerplate and HTML5 Reset, do I always need to use one of these to ensure maximum compatibility?

Comment: @IMB - I'd definitely recommend some kind of reset. You'll also want to use HTM5Shiv or Modernizr to help compatibility with old versions of IE. I'd also suggest asking this as a new question here on SO, as you'll get more responses.