# red source code - Doctype tag

Tags: html, tags, doctype

when checking the source code of a site on firefox I got this on red

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Is my understanding that the red source sometimes means wrongly closed tags or errors of some type.

Can somebody explain why the "Transitional" tag is viewed in red while the "Strict" tag is viewed normally ?

Where can I find the rules for me to check which "DOCTYPE" tag I need to have on my site ?

It is relevant to have one ?

Thanks

Comment: "Where can I find the rules for me to check which "DOCTYPE" tag I need to have on my site ?" --> What about simply: `<!DOCTYPE html>` (for HTML5)?

Comment: Not an issue.. this is default... See the reference:  http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Firefox highlights HTML transitional doctype in red?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775005/why-firefox-highlights-html-transitional-doctype-in-red)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important first: Yes, it's relevant to have a doctype tag.

Without a doctype tag your page will be rendered in quirks mode. That basically means that the browser tries to be compatible with the oldest HTML version it knows, usually something like HTML 3.2, and the oldest Javascript version that it knows. In Internet Explorer it also means that it uses [the non-standard box model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug), which can mess up your layout completely.

You can find valid doctype tags at the [W3C Recommended list of Doctype declarations](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here red color does not indicate an error but a warning, or just information. If you mouse over the red text, Firefox shows you a tooltip that tells that the document is rendered in “[almost standards mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko%27s_Almost_Standards_Mode)”, as opposite to “standards mode” triggered by a Strict DTD.

The odds are that this does not matter. If it does and you prefer “standards mode”, use a Strict DTD. In validation, you can then manually override this by selecting the Transitional DTD from a dropdown, if your markup is meant to be Transitional.