# Drop down menus in firefox are not appearing where they are supposed to be

Tags: html, css, firefox

Good evening all I am working on a page and when I tested the page in firefox the drop down menus on the page were not dropping directly down. They were actually appearing at the bottom of the page. I tried a css reset but that is not working. What I believe is happening is that the menus are falling below the div that is righ under the nav section but take a look and let me know what you think. Thanks. Ive included all the code for my index page. If anybody could also point me twoards a method of displaying this nicely in older versions of IE that would be great too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


<!-- adds the small logo to title tab -->
<title>Shattered Kingdoms</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--Stylesheets-->
<link rel="stylesheet"href="style.css"/>
<!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1//style.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1//jquery.js"></script>
<!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
<link res="stylesheet"href="reset.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="outpage">
    <div id="mainpage">
    <div id="smallnav">
        211/500 users online
    </div>
    <div id="logospace">
    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section id=wowslider-container1 -->
<div id="wowslider-container1">
<div class="ws_images"><ul>
    <li><img src="data1/images/1ff7hqgh.jpg" alt="Shattered Kingdoms" title="Shattered Kingdoms" id="wows1_0"/></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/u7prvqgh.jpg" alt="Huge Worlds" title="Huge Worlds" id="wows1_1"/></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/szao1yrh.jpg" alt="Jesus" title="Minecraft Jesus" id="wows1_2"/></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/rq0mingh.jpg" alt="Meth Guys" title="Minecraft Meth Heads" id="wows1_3"/></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/mnbojogh.jpg" alt="Swords" title="Swords" id="wows1_4"/></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/la5v7i4h.jpg" alt="Lego" title="A.D.D. sufferers dream!" id="wows1_5"/></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/iymmqjeh.jpg" alt="Swords2" title="More Swords" id="wows1_6"/></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/e9max09h.jpg" alt="Cowlove" title="Beastiality"   id="wows1_7"/></li>
    <li><img src="data1/images/9xpex0oh.jpg" alt="Expansive landscape"    title="Expansive Landscape" id="wows1_8"/></li>

</ul></div>
<div class="ws_bullets"><div>
<a href="#" title="Shattered Kingdoms"><img src="data1/tooltips/1ff7hqgh.jpg" alt="Shattered  Kingdoms"/>1</a>
<a href="#" title="u7prvQgh"><img src="data1/tooltips/u7prvqgh.jpg" alt="u7prvQgh"/>2</a>
<a href="#" title="SZAo1yRh"><img src="data1/tooltips/szao1yrh.jpg" alt="SZAo1yRh"/>3</a>
<a href="#" title="Rq0miNgh"><img src="data1/tooltips/rq0mingh.jpg" alt="Rq0miNgh"/>4</a>
<a href="#" title="MnbOjOGh"><img src="data1/tooltips/mnbojogh.jpg" alt="MnbOjOGh"/>5</a>
<a href="#" title="lA5V7I4h"><img src="data1/tooltips/la5v7i4h.jpg" alt="lA5V7I4h"/>6</a>
<a href="#" title="iymMqjEh"><img src="data1/tooltips/iymmqjeh.jpg" alt="iymMqjEh"/>7</a>
<a href="#" title="e9Max09h"><img src="data1/tooltips/e9max09h.jpg" alt="e9Max09h"/>8</a>
<a href="#" title="9XPeX0oh"><img src="data1/tooltips/9xpex0oh.jpg" alt="9XPeX0oh"/>9</a>

</div></div>
<span class="wsl"><a href="http://wowslider.com">Slider HTML5</a> by WOWSlider.com v4.7</span>
<a href="#" class="ws_frame"></a>
<div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1//wowslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1//script.js"></script>
<!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
    </div>
<nav>
        <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Register/login</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Email Password</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Answer Security Questions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>



</ul>
    </nav>        


    <div id="article">
    <h1>Content Goes Here</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="legaljibjab">
    copyright John Snow 2013
    </div>

 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS

```
k@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
html{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#outpage{
margin:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
border:black solid medium;
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,102) 24%,rgb(153,153,153) 62%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,102) 24%,rgb(153,153,153) 62%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.24, rgb(0,0,102)), color-stop(0.62,  rgb(153,153,153)));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,102) 24%,rgb(153,153,153) 62%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,102) 24%,rgb(153,153,153) 62%);
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom), rgb(0,0,102) 24%,rgb(153,153,153) 62%);}
#mainpage{
width:1024px;
height:100%;

margin:0 auto;
background:#FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333333; /* all latest browser */
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333333; /* Firefox older version*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333333; /* Chrome/Safari older version */
 }


#smallnav{
height:20px;

width:1024px;
background:#FFFFFF;
}
#logospace{
width:auto;
height:365px;
}
#logospace>h1{
text-align:center;}

nav{
height:80px;
width:1024px;
}

ul{
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;

}

nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
background: #efefef; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 75px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
z-index:100;
 }
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
li {
float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
 nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 15px 40px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
 nav ul ul li a:hover {
            background: #4b545f;}           }
 nav ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
 }

li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 1em;
  left: 0;
  }

 li > ul {
 top: auto;
 left: auto;
 }

li:hover ul, li.over ul{ display: block; }

#article{
height:500px;
width:1024px;

background:#FFFFFF;}
 #article>h1{
text-align:center;}
 #legaljibjab{
height:30px;
width:1024px;
border:black solid thin;
background:#FFFFFF;}
```

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Step 1: get rid of the XHTML transitional doctype.  Right off the bat your code is now having to struggle with "almost standards mode" across all of the browsers.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775005/why-firefox-highlights-html-transitional-doctype-in-red   Once you change that to a standards mode doctype, then see how things are responding and start coding your HTML using the standards

Comment: So what the article is saying is to just change it to 
    <!DOCTYPE html>?
tried that out it did adjust the placement of a few things but still no dice on the drop down menu items

Comment: Here is a link to the page it worked fine today in chrome I dont know if ive screwed it up with code changes in school because they dont have chrome at my campus...
http://vps8383.inmotionhosting.com/~jsnow/

Comment: Keep it as HTML. Since the source in your question wasn't real XHTML anyway, if would fail to load entirely on a browser that treats it as XHTML. And you should get rid of the comment above the DOCTYPE. The DOCTYPE should be the _very first_ thing in the file, no matter what the W3C standard says.

Comment: By the way, there are other errors in your source. Missing spaces between attribute values, double slashes in URIs etc. Run your source through a validator. Oh, and the cause of the problem (see my answer) was the padding of 125px, while your source in the question said that the padding was 75px. Don't do that; it causes needless confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal padding on the `ul` in the `nav` is too large, causing the menu bar to wrap. (Not sure why it doesn't do the same in other browsers though.)

Solution: decrease the padding a bit until the menu bar fits on one line.